# how to open a document when loading a web page

Tags: javascript, html, web, onload

I want to open a excel document while loading a web page but i don't know how. I tried this:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    window.open("file:///D://Files/doc.xlsx");
}
</script>
<body onload="myFunction()">
</body>
```

But it didn't work. I want to mention that it has to be done for IE8 and less.

Comment: Are you using native HTML?

Comment: So all the users have the file at that location? Or is this just for you?

Answer (score 0):

Add tag `<script>` to `<head>`

```
<head>
  <script>
   function myFunction() {
      window.open("file:///D://Files/doc.xlsx");
   }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">
</body>
```